# Are there any shortcut keys for Google Translate web interface?

Tags: google-translate

I use [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/) often and I wished there was a shortcut key for swapping language. Are there any?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Google Translate now has a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> hotkey for swapping languages:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: The key combination unfortunately conflicts with Firefox's "save screenshot region" hotkey.

Comment: It also conflicts with windows switch keyboard, and Awesome Screenshot.

Comment: @EresDev In my case it works as expected and it does not interfere with keyboard switch (Windows 10). I got 3 different keyboards installed.

Comment: As user598527 said, the key combination conflicts with Firefox's save screenshot region hotkey. Since I don't use this hotkey I disabled it with instructions from here: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/take-screenshots-firefox

"To disable Firefox Screenshots:

Type about:config in the address bar and press Return.
A warning page may appear.
Type extensions.screenshots.disabled in the Search field.
Click the Toggle button next to this preference to set it to true. 

Once you have toggled this preference, you are all set. Screenshots will no longer run in your browser."

Comment: "Command + shift + s" on macOS.

Answer (score 8):

If you use Google Chrome, this extension may be useful to you.

[Keyboard Shortcuts for Google Translate](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/keyboard-shortcuts-for-go/akjhnbnjanndggbcegmdggfjjclohjpo)

It allows to use keyboard shortcut for Google Translate on Web.

```
[Option](PC:[Alt]) + [0-7] keys are bound to each indexed button.
```

- lang-swap button -> Option + 0
- button1 -> Option + 1
- button2 -> Option + 2
- button3 -> Option + 3
- button4 -> Option + 4
- button5 -> Option + 5
- button6 -> Option + 6
- button7 -> Option + 7

Comment: In Chrome Alt/Ctrl + [ 1, 2 ... ] will switch tabs.

Answer (score 3):

I use this trick (in Google Chrome):

Go to `chrome://settings/searchEngines`,
in the **Other search engines** section click **Add**:

For the **Search engine** field enter a name of your choice.

For the **Keyword** choose a shortcut, typically a short word to go to translate from the address bar.

In the URL field enter this (this is for English> Arabic translation):

```
https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=ar&text=%s
```

then click Save.

here's a screenshot (En> Ar):

[image]

*Change the `sl` and `tl` values to change the source-language and the to-language respectively,
for example the French to Russian translation, the URL would be:*

```
https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=fr&tl=ru&text=%s
```

Usage:

In the address bar type your shortcut (tr) then press tap then your text to translate:
[image]

press enter to go directly to translate with your text being translated into your to-language

Answer (score 1):

There is none, but Google Translator Toolkit has [some](https://support.google.com/translate/toolkit/answer/147834?hl=en), and some browser extensions such as [Google Translate™ Hotkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-translate-hotkey/lhfibdjmgcoeokogjlbikafjeplnajfp?hl=en) add a couple of hotkeys.